# How to select the second point where derivative is greater than 1 in r?

Tags: r, clustering, dbscan

I'm looking for the exact value of epsilon to run the `DBSCAN` clustering algorithm.

Here's the `KNN` distance plot.

[image]

This chart has two flex points. I need the second flex point. I'm using the following code:

```
# evaluate kNN distance
dist <- dbscan::kNNdist(iris, 4)

# order result
dist <- dist[order(dist)]

# scale
dist <- dist / max(dist)

# derivative
ddist <- diff(dist) / ( 1 / length(dist))

# get first point where derivative is higher than 1
knee <- dist[length(ddist)- length(ddist[ddist > 1])]
```

How can improve my code to get second point where derivative is higher than 1?

Comment: Please **do not post duplicates**: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49382834/1060350

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the which method, it returns you the index where it satisfies the criteria.

For example:

```
> a <- c(-0.123, 1.2, 0.3, 8, -0.678)
> b <- which(a>1)
[1] 2 4
> b[2]
[1] 4
```